# Preventing boredom creep with hobby projects

Tags: motivation

This question is directed more towards the hobbyist developer rather than professional game developers.  Quite frequently while developing a game I'll get bored staring at the same exact game scene after days or weeks of work (while new features only slowly creep in) that I find myself abandoning projects and starting new ones, never really finishing what I've started.

How do you prevent yourself from getting bored with a hobby or side project?  What tips/tricks/techniques do you use to keep yourself motivated to actually finish a project?

Comment: Check out the highest-voted question on the site.  :) (It's closed, now, because it's impossible to answer.  But it has historical value.)